# Centos 8, yum update command not working. given following error. can't find php-common-7.2

Tags: centos8

1. I've tried to remove php-common-7.2 but couldn't find where it located.

   ```
    Problem: package php-pecl-igbinary-3.2.2-1.el8.remi.7.2.x86_64 requires php(api) = 20170718-64, but none of the providers can be installed
    - package php-pecl-igbinary-3.2.2-1.el8.remi.7.2.x86_64 requires php(zend-abi) = 20170718-64, but none of the providers can be installed
    - cannot install both php-common-7.2.34-3.el8.remi.x86_64 and php-common-7.4.16-1.el8.remi.x86_64
    - cannot install both php-common-7.2.34-4.el8.remi.x86_64 and php-common-7.4.16-1.el8.remi.x86_64
    - cannot install the best update candidate for package php-pecl-igbinary-3.2.1-1.el8.remi.7.4.x86_64
    - problem with installed package php-common-7.4.16-1.el8.remi.x86_64
    - package php-common-7.2.24-1.module_el8.2.0+313+b04d0a66.x86_64 is filtered out by modular filtering
    (try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
   ```
2. My server configuration is

   ```
    NAME="CentOS Linux"
    VERSION="8"
    ID="centos"
    ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
    VERSION_ID="8"
    PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
    PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 8"
    ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
    CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:8"
    HOME_URL="https://centos.org/"
    BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"
    CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-8"
    CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="8"
    Apache Web Server
    php7.4-cli
    using Webmin & virtaulmin`
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to install igbinary extension for PHP 7.2 with PHP 7.4. This cannot work.

For a proper configuration, please follow the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

And not enough information for more help:

```
rpm -qa php\*
dnf repolist
dnf module list PHP
```

Comment: I've a live website on this server. which is running on php7.4. If I run this "rpm -qa php\*" , will it remove php7.4 also???

Comment: all commands in above answer are only used to retrieve useful information.
Please check man of each command before using them